# Show content type field on front page

Tags: nodes

I created a content type, I need to place several fields on *front page* (text field, dropdown list and button). How can this be done? Do I need to use the *Form API*?

Please let me know what's the best way to go about this.

P.S. I m fairly new to Drupal. Coming from Joomla.

Comment: Do you mean you want to put a form on the front page with a text field, dropdown and button? Or do you want to display values from these fields? For creating a form see [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).

Comment: Why you want that form in front page any Survey or Create node ?

Comment: Hi, Thank to all. Yes, I want to put a form on the front page with a text field, dropdown and button. I mean create node..

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option for You is the module "[Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform)",

but you can solve your problem also by **Form api**, though in that case you must create custom module and write enough code...

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply, but Webform module for survey tasks?

Answer (score 0):

To display the node form on the front page you can use [Form block module](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock). This module fulfill your requirement.

**Form Block:**

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or node creation forms in blocks. This is particularly useful for including forms on panels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  "[webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform)"

Using webform you can create all kind of fields, Also you can display that form fields as a block using webforms settings, And you can display that block anywhere on your site.

Here is description, How you can create a block for your webform "[webform in a block](https://www.drupal.org/node/1447436)"